# How to specify custom location (absolute path) to load areas in asp.net core mvc?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to load areas from a custom directory by specifying the **absolute path (C:/WebApplication7/MS/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml)**. I tried specifying *AreaLocationFormats* in *Startup.cs* and implementing *IViewLocationExpander*. Both of these work fine when I give a **relative path (/MS/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml)** but I need to load the view by providing the exact path of the directory as my Views will be present in a separate directory.
Is this possible in some way?

```
services.AddControllersWithViews()
                 .AddRazorOptions(options =>
                 {
                     options.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add(@"/MS/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml");
                 });
```

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews()
                 .AddRazorOptions(options =>
                 {
                     options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander());
                 });

public class ViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
        {
            //{2} is area, {1} is controller,{0} is the action
            string[] locations = new string[] { "/MS/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" };
            return locations.Union(viewLocations);          //Add mvc default locations after ours
        }

        public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
        {
            context.Values["customviewlocation"] = nameof(ViewLocationExpander);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the specific path of view in areas, you can set it in `app.UseEndpoints`.

Suppose my areas name is `MyArea`.

In the startup.cs `Configure` method:

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "MyArea",
         pattern: "C:/WebApplication7/MS/{area:exists}/Views/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}.cshtml");
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

With some more research I was able to do it by configuring a new [FileProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** nuget package and the line in Startup.cs

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => {
    options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(@"C:/WebApplication7"));
});
```

Details about configuring file provider : https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14593

With FileProvider defined both of the above methods work fine.